# Mounting a shared folder with a virtual machine using Oracle VM virtual box manager

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machines, network-share, ubuntu-20.04

I've done this before but I just updated Oracle VM virtual box manager, I'm on the step where I select the folder to link to my own host computer but it's not letting select the okay button to mount it. Does anyone know what the issue could be? I've tried different variations of options, different folders, used different virtual machines to try the same thing, etc., I'm at a loss.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: vm-mount-folder]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind it was already mounted lol it says it right in the folder in the screenshot